# Groovy :: @Mixin methods override target class methods

Tags: groovy, mixins

```
class A {  
  def test() { println "parent" }  
} 

@Mixin(A)  
class B {  
  def test() { println "child" }  
} 

new B().test() // prints "parent", but I am expecting it to print "child"
```

This looks like some kind of reverse inheritance.

Are mixins only to be used as a means to define new methods?

I can of course use conventional inheritance and go with extends, but the use case entails a form builder where each domain has a unique form implementation and I'd like to, in my application controller, catch form requests and do a MyUniqueDomainForm.mixin DefaultFormMethods (so I only need to define default methods when I need to, as well as not having to import my.package.app.DefaultFormMethods in each form class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you `mixin` will overload whatever is already there...

In this example, at compile time `B.test()` overloads the inherited `A.test()` method

But then at runtime, `A.test()` is added via the `mixin`, which re-overloads the previously overloaded method

If it was not this way round you would not be able to alter the existing characteristics of a class using `mixins`

ie (this is a silly example, but I believe it gets my point across):

```
class AddNotMinus {
  static def minus( int a, int b ) {
     a + b
  }
}

Integer.mixin AddNotMinus
println 10 - 10
```

prints `20`

Comment: Thanks Tim, I assumed that was the case.  Groovy "advertises" mixins as an alternative to inheritance, but the implied parent-overrides-child-method is not mentioned (from what I have seen). So, one then goes with standard child extends parent to get desired behavior I assume (i.e. no other @annotion to pull this off?)

Comment: No probs.  Not that I know of...  Other than adding a property of type `A` and marking it as `@Delegate` :-/